# AMP won't let images load

Tags: amp-html, amp-img

I'm trying to use [AMP](https://www.ampproject.org) in my app. I could get my images with:

```html
<img src="{{url('storage/images')}}/{{$post->image}}" alt="{{$post->title}}" class="img-fluid">
```

but since I added AMP they won't load anymore:

```html
<amp-img src="{{url('storage/images')}}/{{$post->image}}" alt="{{$post->title}}" class="img-fluid"></amp-img>
```

Any idea what is happening?

## UPDATE 1

this is what i added to my site header:

```html
<html amp lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<!-- amp -->
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script><!-- must besecond child -->
    <link rel="canonical" href="{{url()->current()}}">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": [
          "logo.jpg"
        ]
      }
    </script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
<!-- ./amp -->
```

here is errors i'm getting in my console:

```html
Powered by AMP ⚡ HTML – Version 1524089272632 http://mynewsite.pp/blog/rtger
viewer-impl.js:1025:11
Error: Layout not supported: container. The element did not specify a layout attribute. Check https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/control_layout and the respective element documentation for details.​​​
log.js:504:16
Error: Layout not supported: container. The element did not specify a layout attribute. Check https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/control_layout and the respective element documentation for details.​​​
log.js:504:16
Error: Layout not supported: container. The element did not specify a layout attribute. Check https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/control_layout and the respective element documentation for details.​​​
log.js:504:16
Error: Layout not supported: container. The element did not specify a layout attribute. Check https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/control_layout and the respective element documentation for details.​​​
log.js:504:16
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://mynewsite.pp/themes/admin/assets/icon/icofont/fonts/icofont.ttf?v=1.0.0-beta”[Learn More]
lounge.bundle.44672f4cc4bed783e5e2f3cb12270277.js:1:1280
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://mynewsite.pp/themes/dup/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2”[Learn More]
lounge.bundle.44672f4cc4bed783e5e2f3cb12270277.js:1:1280
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://mynewsite.pp/themes/dup/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2”[Learn More]
lounge.bundle.44672f4cc4bed783e5e2f3cb12270277.js:1:1280
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://mynewsite.pp/themes/dup/fonts/Linearicons-Free.woff2?w118d”[Learn More]
lounge.bundle.44672f4cc4bed783e5e2f3cb12270277.js:1:1280
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://mynewsite.pp/themes/dup/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2”[Learn More]
lounge.bundle.44672f4cc4bed783e5e2f3cb12270277.js:1:1280
This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!
rtger
Unhandled promise rejection undefined
p13n.min.js:1:41081
```

Comment: [*"`amp-img` components, like all externally fetched AMP resources, must be given an explicit size"*](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-img) - I'd guess that's the problem, but have you checked the console for warnings from AMP? See e.g. https://www.ampproject.org/docs/troubleshooting/validation_errors.

Comment: Why are you using amp? <amp-img> is not a tag/element

Comment: @AAShakil it is if you're using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_Mobile_Pages

Comment: @jonrsharpe i get this in console `Powered by AMP ⚡ HTML – Version 1524089272632 http://mynewsite.pp/blog/rtger
viewer-impl.js:1025:11
Error: Layout not supported: container. The element did not specify a layout attribute. Check https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/control_layout and the respective element documentation for details.​​​
log.js:504:16`

Comment: @tambre i just tagged my images as example in official website, where i'm wrong?

Comment: @jonrsharpe but <amp-img> is not an element. So, browsers will ignore it.

Comment: So did you check that link and the respective element documentation? Please put a [mcve] in the question itself. Also @tambre is talking about the SO tags you put on your question, which I've already fixed - please double-check that the tags you're applying are accurate by reading their descriptions.

Comment: @mafortis could you please tell if any error or warning in your browsers console!!

Comment: @AAShakil they won't ignore it, they'll probably just render it as an inline element in the absence of further information; arbitrary element names are valid in HTML5. But there *is* further information, provided by the AMP framework. If you're not familiar with that framework, it's unlikely that you'll be able to help the OP. If you're interested in finding out more about it there are relevant links in the question and my comments.

Comment: guys i updated my question, so you can see what i've done in general maybe i did a mistake somewhere there..

Comment: @jonrsharpe updated my question

Comment: @tambre  updated my question

Comment: There is NO WAY to help you here unless you show ALL the code. Read @jonsharpe comment - you nead MVCE. The problem may be an incorrectly structured JSON files; it might be a CORS problem; it might be a dozen other issues.

Comment: you can't inject JSON in HEAD - there no processor to do that. Are you trying to generate the page from a handlebar application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure `width, height` are defined on `<amp-img>` tag otherwise it will not load.

Comment: why this was down voted? `width` and `height` are needed and without them images wont show. `layout` is optional 
had same issue and adding width and height solved it (before coming here to be honestly) upvoted

Comment: @BlueBot first of all thanks for the up-vote, second: some people here are just up-vote/down-vote to earn badges that's all (LOL).